# Javascript Regex: How to find index of each subexpression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have the string: `BLAH BLAH BLAH copy 2`.
I want to find the index of the two pieces, the word 'copy' and a number that may follow the word copy.

I have the regex: `/(copy)\s+([0-9]+)$/i` which successfully matches copy and 2 from the above string.  How can I find the index of the number 2? I know I can use .index to find the position of the matched test 'copy 2', but I would like to get the position of '2' so that I can increment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace the copy number with an incremented number, use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) plus a replacer function:

```
'BLAH BLAH BLAH copy 2'.replace(/(copy )(\d+)/, function (s, s1, s2) {
    return s1 + (Number(s2) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go with regex `/^(.*?copy\s+)(\d+)$/i` and then length of $1 is a position of $2 (copy number).

**Edit:** Your test code is ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnTVD/)):

```
var str = "BLAH BLAH BLAH copy 2";
var m = str.match(/^(.*?copy\s+)(\d+)$/i);
alert("Found '" + m[2] + "' at position " + m[1].length);
```

Comment: Not always. \s+ means there could be 1 or more spaces.

Comment: No, you do not know how much whitespace there is.

Comment: Yes, it will work ***always***, regardless of how many whitespace characters are there :)

Comment: My comment was posted well before you updated your answer. Apropos, I see no good reason for inserting `.*?` here, which is not backwards- compatible, and the `^` anchor that also was not in the original expression.

Comment: @PointedEars - Well, `.*?` may be changed to `.*` if there is `$` (don't know if OP wants allow some extra text behind *copy N*), but how the hell you want to get index by length of `$1` without `^`..? Teach me!

Comment: The update history does not have the wrong answer that says the number index was just `.index + 4`. It might have been by someone else. But Steve saw it, too.

Comment: @PointedEars - Not mine, boy... (you should clean up your irrelevant comments then)

Comment: You want to watch your manners. As for the index, if you replace `^(.*?` with `(`, it will still work if you add `m.index` as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the regular expression slightly, the index of the number can be computed:

```
var matches = "BLAH BLAH BLAH copy 2".match(/(copy)(\s+)([0-9]+)$/i);
var numberIndex = matches.index + matches[1].length + matches[2].length;
```

But you really do not need that in order to increment the number:

```
var matches = "BLAH BLAH BLAH copy 2".match(/(copy)\s+([0-9]+)$/i);
var incremented = (+matches[2]) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex `/(copy)\s+([0-9]+)$/i` to `/^((.*)(copy)\s+)([0-9]+)$/i`

Then the position of `copy` is the length of `$2` and  the position of the numbers is the length of `$1`. The number will be in `$4`