# JavaScript RegEx with separate group indexes

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

Let's say I have a regular expression `/([a-z]+):([0-9]+)/` and a sample text `hello:123`.

Is there a way for me to execute this expression so that it returns all capturing groups along with positions for each group?

For example the result should be something like `[["hello", 0], ["123", 6]]`.

As far as I found, the regular expression only returns the position for the whole match, which is not enough for what I need :( Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

In PHP, this can be achieved with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag, but I need the same behaviour for JS

**SOLUTION:**

In this thread [Get index of each capture in a JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934353/get-index-of-each-capture-in-a-javascript-regex) there is a class `MultiRegExp2` which allows for this functionality https://github.com/valorize/MultiRegExp2

Comment: You could iterate the matches and keep track of the position yourself in the loop... each match may also have the position hidden in a private member or otherwise

Comment: The thing is, I need all positions within a single match. In PHP there is a `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag, but I have no idea how to do the same in JS.

Comment: Sounds like a job for split or indexof... and then manually find the offsets at the worst case but using a match collection should also work

Comment: I am afraid it is more complicated but I've found a solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934353/get-index-of-each-capture-in-a-javascript-regex thread. I'll update my question to include the solution