# JS RegExp capture all groups and pos for each match

Tags: javascript, regex

**Statement:**
I am new to RegExp and trying to learn capture groups in javascripts

1. I am using https://regex101.com/r/COYhIc/1 for testing
2. see attached image for character pos column of each match by https://regex101.com

**Objective:**

1. I want to print all matches and groups at console **(Done)**
2. I want to print character position of each match [see image]**(remaining)**

[image]

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/p28fmdk4/68/

**JavaScript:**

```js
function parseQuery(query) {
  var isRE = query.match(/^\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)$/);
  if (isRE) {
    try {
      query = new RegExp(isRE[1], isRE[2]);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  return query;
}
var str = $('#str').val();
var regex = parseQuery($('#reg').val());
//
var result;
var match_no = 0;
var output = '';
while ((result = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  match_no++;
  output += `\nMatch ${match_no}\n`;
  output += `Full Match, ${ result[0]} , Pos\n`;
  for (i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
    output += `Group ${i}, ${ result[i]} , Pos\n`;
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934353/get-index-of-each-capture-in-a-javascript-regex

Answer (score 1):

According to docs [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), you can retrieve it using `index` property. So I would add this line into your snippet to retrieve column position for your full match:

```
`${result.index}-${result.index + result[0].length}`
```

For subgroups, JS doesn't retrieve index, so a workaround can be achieved using indexOf:

```
const initialSubGroupIndex = str.indexOf(result[i], result.index);
`${initialSubGroupIndex}-${initialSubGroupIndex + result[i].length}`
```

Comment: but waht about group 1 and 2 ? i have issue there ,full match is correct but rest are worng

Comment: @django unfortunately, js doesn't offer accessing index of groups by default, what I would do in your situation is searching in your actual string `str` for your found groups result[1] and result[2]. something like `str.indexOf(result[1])`

Comment: use fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/p28fmdk4/68/ , i updated it to match extacly with  https://regex101.com/r/COYhIc/1 and see the difference for group 2

Comment: ```str.indexOf(result[1])``` can yield worng result as group 2 with value ```100``` is repeated twice

Comment: @django yup, that's a good opportunity to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)'s second argument: https://jsfiddle.net/tyje1zbc/

Comment: @django Updated my answer !

Comment: None of the solutions can pass the test case str = `aaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, regex = `/a(a*)a/g`. It's simply not possible to find the index of the subgroup - you can only do it when the string captured appears only once in the match

Comment: @guijob https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/p28fmdk4/90/ ,  ```Group 1``` pos should be ```1-13``` as per https://regex101.com  but it is ```0-12 ```

Comment: @django yeah, it doesn't fit in all situations but it does for your particular problem. Besides, I don't see generic solution for this instead of crafting your own regex interpreter or using a 3th party lib.

Answer (score 1):

In your output field use `index` and `lastIndex`. `exec` returns an object with a index property.

```
output += `Full Match, ${ result[0]} , Pos ${result.index} - ${regex.lastIndex}\n `;
```

### Update for the groups:

I have used a small logic to get the indices:

```
var m = new RegExp(result[i]);
output += `Group ${i}, ${ result[i]}, Pos ${$('#str').val().match(m).index} - ${regex.lastIndex} \n`;
```

```js
function parseQuery(query) {
  var isRE = query.match(/^\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)$/);
  if (isRE) {
    try {
      query = new RegExp(isRE[1], isRE[2]);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  return query;
}
var str = $('#str').val();
var regex = parseQuery($('#reg').val());
//
var result;
var match_no = 0;
var output = '';
while ((result = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  match_no++;
  output += `\nMatch ${match_no}\n`;
  output += `Full Match, ${ result[0]} , Pos ${result.index} - ${regex.lastIndex}\n `;
  for (i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
    var m = new RegExp(result[i]);
    output += `Group ${i}, ${ result[i]}, Pos ${$('#str').val().match(m).index} - ${regex.lastIndex} \n`;
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="str">String:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="str" value="source=100, delta=2, source=2121, delta=5">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="regex">Regex:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reg" value="/(source=(\d+))/g">
  </div>
  <div id="result">

  </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yazue4kg/)

Comment: what about groups ?  it is ok for full match but not for group 2

Comment: use fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/p28fmdk4/68/ , i updated it to match extacly with  https://regex101.com/r/COYhIc/1 and see the difference for group 2

Comment: @django Updated the answer !

Comment: FYI I have used the old js fiddle, but it works fine. :)

Comment: None of the solutions can pass the test case str = `aaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, regex = `/a(a*)a/g`. It's simply not possible to find the index of the subgroup - you can only do it when the string captured appears only once in the match